# ¿Como sumar el resultado de un WHILE en SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, while, sql

Buen día mi ejercicio dice lo siguiente:

Realizar un procedimiento almacenado que realice la siguiente suma utilizando un while.

(2i+1) = [2(0)+1] + [2(1)+1] + [2(2)+1] + [2(3)+1] + [2(4)+1]= 25

Ya realice el While, pero mi resultado es 1, 3, 5, 7 y 9. Necesito que mi resultado final sea la suma de esos números.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_SUMA
AS
DECLARE @i INT, @x INT, @total INT 
SET @i = 0
SET @x= 1
WHILE (@i<=4)
BEGIN 
SET @x = 2 * @i + 1
SET @i = @i+1 
PRINT @x  
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saca el PRINT del WHILE, y usa la variable @total, que la declaras y no la utilizas, para sumar cada término sucesivo, como indica el planteamiento.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_SUMA
AS
    DECLARE @i INT, @x INT, @total INT
    SET @x = 1
    SET @total = 0
    SET @i = 0
    WHILE (@i <= 4)
        BEGIN 
            SET @x = 2 * @i + 1
            SET @total = @total + @x
            SET @i = @i + 1 
        END
    PRINT @total
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Bro, no había visto mi error. Excelente contribución

Answer (score 2):

Este ejercicio es un problema con la enseñanza de SQL ya que previene que se piense en un sentido de lenguaje semi-declarativo (donde se le indica que hacer) para pensar en un procesamiendo procedimental (donde se le indica como hacerlo).

En SQL utilizamos tablas o en su caso vistas. En este ejemplo, crearé una tabla con los números del 0 al 9999.

```
CREATE TABLE numeros( n int);

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n) --10 filas
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b --10 x 10 = 100 filas
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b --100 x 100 = 10,000 filas
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    --ROW_NUMBER crea una numeración consecutiva y le restamos 1 para iniciar desde cero
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 n 
    FROM E4
)
INSERT INTO numeros
SELECT n
FROM cteTally;
```

Teniendo esa tabla, el proceso queda muy sencillo en SQL. Sin necesidad de WHILE, de variables o de todas las declaraciones que hiciste.

```
SELECT SUM(2 * n + 1) 
FROM numeros
WHERE n <= 4;
```

La tabla de números se puede (y debe) quedar de forma permanente en la base de datos y se le pueden agregar más valores y un índice. O se puede dejar como vista o como una función en línea que reciba un valor inicial y un rango.

Comment: Me gusta lo que planteas, pero para lograr lo que se buscaba bastaría con:
WITH
E(n) AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)) E(n)) SELECT SUM(2 * n + 1)  FROM E
y te evitas meter nada en base de datos y usar ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: ¿Y que pasa cuando cambian el problema para que se sumen los siguientes 100 números? Di la solución que puede ser incrementada sin cambiar el código (salvo por el parámetro).

Comment: Sí, es cierto, si cambian el problema dentro de ciertos parámetros, adaptar la solución es sencillo, pero pueden cambiarlo de muchas maneras, y tendrías que rehacerlo todo igualmente. En este caso, se busca una solución puntual a un problema puntual. Meter tablas en base de datos que pueden no volver a usarse en mucho tiempo (con el riesgo de olvidarse de que existen cuando vuelvas a necesitarlas) es una bonita solución teórica, pero no práctica. Pero como digo, me gusta tu respuesta.

Comment: Las tablas de números no deben ser olvidadas, son muy útiles para distintos problemas. Las uso para crear calendarios, para navegar cadenas de texto, separar valores en separados por comas o patrones, encontrar valores faltantes en secuencias, cálculos matemáticos, etc. Te recomiendo que busques más información de tablas de números (o _tally tables_ en inglés) para que veas su funcionalidad.

Comment: Como ya te digo, tienes razón, si las vas a usar es una muy buena idea, pero es que todas esas cosas generalmente se hacen desde un programa, no desde sql. El tema en este caso sigue siendo que este es un problema puntual que requiere una solución puntual.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo imprimiendo los resultados y de una manera mas simplificada con el operador += (Sql Server 2017+)

```
DECLARE @i int = 0, @total int = 0;
WHILE(@i<=4)
BEGIN
    SET @total += 2 * @i + 1;
    PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('[2(%i)+1] = %i', @i, @total);
    SET @i = @i + 1;    
END
PRINT @total;
```